# How to create sparse matrix for convolution operation

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

As per I know convolution operation is just a matrix multiplication of sparse matrix with inputs,  how to form the sparse matrix in python or maybe in pytorch

Comment: Probably it would be useful if you can edit your question to share what you have done and where you are stuck with some examples. Check out the [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.